# Video recording app for Android that can record without audio while on a phone call

Tags: android, camera, video-recording

If on a phone call on a Samsung Galaxy S9+, I can only take pictures but not record video from the camera (NOT screen recording).  I have no desire to capture the audio, but I would like to be able to take a video without audio while on the call.  Is there an app which does this?  Ideally from a reputable developer. Paid is fine.

To clarify, there is no desire to record the call itself, just to use the camera to record video like normal as if I was not on the call.

Comment: I would love an app that does this as well.  For your question, you made it clear that you have no need to record the call itself.  Is it okay if the app does record your voice and other ambient sounds along with the video?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I'd prefer not but yes that would be fine as I could always remove the audio later and as long as I was using my headset I shouldn't be recording the other person's audio (legal consideration).

Answer (score 1):

To record a WhatsApp video call on Android, it is necessary to install an app. Android does not natively offer the option, however, some manufacturers natively offer the ability to record the screen (with sound) of your Android smartphone. This is the case with Huawei smartphones in particular. If you do not have such an option, you must download an external application.

To record a WhatsApp video call on Android, then follow these instructions:

1. Download MNML Screen Recorder from the Google Play Store. The application is available for free.
2. Open the application, click on the three dots at the top right, and select Settings.
3. Click on the recording part named Recording and activate Record Audio.
4. Go back to the application and click on Record at the bottom right. A three-second counter starts before you start recording your screen (and sound), and a warning message appears indicating that the application will record everything that will be displayed on the screen. Confirm and the recording will start.
   5.Then open WhatsApp and call the contact you want.
5. Once the conversation is over, click on the stop button (square shape) accessible from the quick notification bar or open the MNML application and click on Stop in the bottom right.
6. Go back to the MNML application. Your WhatsApp video conversation is displayed. You can view it on your smartphone and share it with your friends!

Comment: I want to record the camera from the phone, not the call (please see my note that this is "NOT screen recording" in the question)